# Putting two regex together

Tags: regex

I have two regex:

```
(?i:.*(Acct|Account)).*
```

and

```
(\d{5,}).*`
```

that work separately (finding the word 'account' and finding 5 or more digits).  However, when I put them together (finding the word 'account' in combination with 5 or more digits), the new regex:

```
(?i:.*(Acct|Account)).*(\d{5,}).*
```

doesn't work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: post few examples of the text you're looking at.

Comment: "Account" with text following, then a string of 5 digits, like 12345.

Comment: Account.*?\d{5}

Comment: Works fine for me: https://regex101.com/r/H7GLMt/1

Comment: Maybe your text is split up over multiple lines? Sometimes, `.` does not match line breaks without a specific flag. Or maybe the number appears before 'Account'?

Comment: Ah-ha! That's exactly the problem...the regex works if 'account' and the digit string are on the same line.  I need it to find the account/digit combination if they're on different lines/rows, like in a spreadsheet.

Comment: (?s)(Account(?:.*?\d{5})?|d{5})

Comment: This one picks up the word 'account' when it's on multiple lines, but not if the 5 digit number is on a separate line. By the way, I'm in .NET...

Comment: (?s)((?:Acct|Account)(?:(?:(?!(?:Acct|Account)).)*?\d{5})?|d{5})

Comment: Still no luck.  Here's how the text I'm testing is laid out.  I get a hit on everything but the digits BEFORE 'account' and where 'account' and the digits are on different lines:

Comment: starting text Account with text between 1234567
line
acct 345678
line
2345678 Account
line
Account (put return here)
456789
line
ACCOUNT 1234
line
Accounting 123456

Comment: I loaded a screen shot of my regex and sample text from Expresso to this site: https://prnt.sc/g5ieab - you'll see what is working and what isn't.  I'm looking for the 'account' and 6-digit string on a different line to match.

Comment: The question content should rather be inserted in the question with [edit] than displayed in comments

Answer (score 0):

You can skip over newlines as well:

```
(?i:.*(Acct|Account))(?:.|\n)*(\d{5,})
```